# Counting consecutive values using partitioning - gaps and islands?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm starting to learn `row_number()` and `over()` with partitioning, and I ran into something on this site called Gaps and Islands... I'm trying to understand it all.

My data table:

| Step Number | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Passed |
| 2 | Passed |
| 3 | Passed |
| 4 | Passed |
| 5 | Failed |
| 6 | Failed |
| 7 | Failed |
| 8 | Failed |
| 9 | Failed |
| 10 | Passed |
| 11 | Passed |
| 12 | Passed |

The results I'm trying to get:

| Order | Status | Consecutive Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Passed | 4 |
| 2 | Failed | 5 |
| 3 | Passed | 3 |

This is as far as I've gotten.  The first "Passed" doesn't show up in the recordset, and I can't find where to put a `COUNT()` or whatever function to get the number of rows in a partition.

```sql
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Status) AS 'Order', Status
FROM (
    SELECT *, Steppy = row_number() over (partition by [Status] order by [StepNumber] desc)
    FROM Q1
) A
GROUP BY Status
```

Results:

| Order | Status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Failed |
| 2 | Passed |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following gives your desired results.

Using your step number we can create a sequence from which you can subtract the row-number of each *partition* to greate a *group*, then you can aggregate by this group:

```
with g as (
  select StepNumber, status, 
    Row_Number() over(order by StepNumber) 
    - Row_Number() over(partition by status order by StepNumber) grp
  from t
)
select Row_Number() over(order by grp) [Order],
Status, Count(*) [consecutive counts]
from g
group by Status, grp
```

Comment: Note this *assumes* `StepNumber` will always be incremental; if it's something like an `IDENTITY` that is a poor assumption.

Comment: True that was an assumption - it's just as easy to use a separate row_number I'll amend the query.